# Seamless audio track / music loop - Auto / Automatic / AI / Script

Tags: audio, music, infinite-loop, seamless

I always loop audio tracks for my daily vlog.

It's like audio track is 3 minutes but I make this audio like 20 minutes.

I just find one point near the beginning that also appears near the end.

Then I do nice 2 cuts and just copy paste this middle part few times.

And I have one start + 10x middle part + 1 end. And a viewer can't even feel this is looped in this way or something.

---

And

My question is...

Can I automate this? Some plugin? for premiere or something?

Maybe some program or application that will do this for me?

Music Looper? Audio Track Smart Looper?

Some script? Maybe AI system?

I just wanna don't do this all the time, ep by ep, audio track after another audio track.

It's the thing that I do every single day.

So is this possible? To somehow automate this process :)?

Comment: Why don't you just take the audio clip, make it into a 20-30 minute loop and then save it as a new audio file?

Comment: @DrZoo It doesn't make sense, it's about automation this process. Each time, every day I process music clips like that, and every day is completly another music. I just wanna automate this every-day task.

Comment: It wasn't very clear that you used a different audio track each day. Doing some quick Google searching, it doesn't seem like this tool exists. And for the tools that do, people say you still need to do manual work sometimes. [Sound Exchange beta](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/14935/are-there-tools-to-seamlessly-loop-sounds). Here is [a search I used](http://www.letmegooglethat.com/?q=automatic+seamless+audio+loop) to find some info on other audio forums.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few years old now, but for any one who still finds themselves here after a Google Search you may want to try the free, open-source python CLI program [PyMusicLooper](https://github.com/arkrow/PyMusicLooper)

> **Features**:
>
> - Find loop points within any music file (if they exist).
> - Supports a large set of different audio formats, and all the popular ones (MP3, OGG, M4A, FLAC, WAV, etc).
> - Play the music file endlessly and seamlessly with the best discovered loop.
> - Export to intro/loop/outro sections for editing or seamless playback within any music player that supports gapless playback.
> - Export loop points in samples to a text file (e.g. for use in creating custom themes with seamlessly looping audio).

You can even batch process:

> Export intro/loop/outro sections and loop points of all the songs in the current directory and its subdirectories, to a folder called "Music Loops", processing 4 tracks concurrently.
>
> ```
> pymusiclooper -ret . -o "Music Loops" -n 4
> ```